# I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 . but the system got corrupted and now it's not opening . I fear that I might lose my data

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I tried to boot from USB and it shows my files but I can cannot copy it due to permission issues . I there any way to get my data back? I will be highly thankful. I have very important data

Answer (score 0):

when booting hold down Shift key to go into GRUB menu screen

```
Ubuntu (default)
Ubuntu advanced
memory test
memory test (other options)
```

From the list go into Ubuntu advanced, then pick an earlier release

If its a graphics driver issue, however you can boot up (its just perhaps a blank screen or such), once booted hit ctrl-alt-F1 to go into console where you have access to the command line.  If so this will typically give you access the the internet so any file sharing services like Dropbox will be usable

Comment: I picked some earlier releases but that too are not opening !!

Comment: Seems like my OS got corrupted !! Nothing is working !!

Comment: Does it boot enough to permit you to get the console ?

Comment: I tried to boot from USB and it successfully happened but when I tried to copy my files it shows permission issues . can you suggest me how to change permissions when booting from USB so that I can copy all my data ?

Comment: can you get root from the terminal / console  ?     sudo -i

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong as I am new to Linux . as I boot from USB then by default I have root access. So all I want is that with root I can change permissions of my files on my laptop so that I can copy it to my my external hard drive . but I don't know how to do it !! Can u help me?

Comment: google this :  ubuntu boot from usb drive access files  ....   It suggests link http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17044/move-files-from-a-failing-pc-with-an-ubuntu-live-cd/

Comment: Well I tried sudo nautilus in terminal . it pops a window and from there I am copying my files to my external hard drive  !!!! Seems it's working .

Comment: cool - post that solution as the Answer to help the next person - cheers

Comment: Oh !! Of course... And thak you for helping me !!